# How to show nextText/prevText in jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

According to the [documentation for `nextText`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-nextText):

> The text to display for the next month link. This attribute is one of the regionalisation attributes. With the standard ThemeRoller styling, this value is replaced by an icon.

So, what is the correct way to disable this replacement?

Something like

```
$(".ui-datepicker-header > .ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon")
```

obviously doesn't work because it runs before the elements are actually created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overwrite the styles instead of trying to remove them:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
     background-image: none;
 }
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/54cgQ/1/

**Oct 9, 2014** Updated example with newer versions of jquery, jquery ui:

http://jsfiddle.net/54cgQ/46/

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902367/apply-different-css-to-different-jquery-datepickers

Comment: this answer is clearly not correct, only hide the icon but not show the text