# Apply different CSS to different jQuery datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have several datepickers tied to input fields. They are created in the usual way:

```
$('#input1').datepicker(options1);
$('#input2').datepicker(options2);
```

Now I want to style them differently for each field. But when inspecting the page in Firefox, I see that each datepicker is a `div` with the same `id`: `ui-datepicker-div`! And they aren't descendants or siblings of input fields, so I don't see a way to use the inputs' `id`s in CSS selectors.

Comment: That's really akward because multiple id's should not be used. Are your date-picker-div's wrapped in any way so you could detect them ?

Comment: The jQuery UI Datepicker should not be assigning and `id` to each datepicker. What version are you using? Are you assigning the `id` yourself?

Comment: @EvilP I know they shouldn't be used, but that's what jQuery generates :(

Comment: Yeah I know, you can't change that ;-) are you sure you can't detect in any way if they are wrapped somehow ?

Comment: @BenCarey See "Sample markup" in http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#theming. It shows the same `<div id="ui-datepicker-div" ...` I see. The versions are  jQuery UI 1.8.18 and jQuery 1.7.1 (since that's the one included with jQuery UI). I am not assigning the `id` and in fact, a way to do it would fix the problem :) Do you know one?

Comment: @EvilP They don't seem to be. They are just siblings of the actual page content.

Comment: hmm thats really good question then...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You could loop through each datepicker by using the datepicker class, and then just add a custom id. I am really confused, My datepicker does not have any id's on it!

Comment: @BenCarey But then how do I know which datepicker corresponds to which field?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Can you not wrap the inputs with an element and then select the class from there as a sibling. The jQuery documentation says that it creates an id for the datepicker, however, on a site that I have built using jQuery 1.8.17 (not 1.8.18), there is definitely no id. I also cannot find anything in the changelog!

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov How is it related to the input? Can you post the HTML in your question and I will give it my best

Comment: @BenCarey Unfortunately, even trying to insert the complete HTML in the question makes SO choke (it's over 4500 lines!). Or did you mean the initial page source and not the one after jQuery does its job?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov. WOW!!!! 4500 lines for the HTML!!! That is ridiculous. Is that excluding the Javascript? Have you tried using Firebug (Firefox) or Inspect Element (Chrome) to retrieve the HTML?

Comment: @BenCarey No, that's including Javascript (in particular, there is a lot of Javascript _inside_ timepicker divs).

Comment: That cannot be right, my datepicker is around 220 lines with javascript events inline. Could you possibly post a snippet of the input and parents, along with your javascript (the relevant parts)

Comment: @BenCarey Found the problem :) I was accidentally inserting same JS (unminified, so far) multiple times while generating the page. So it's saner size now.

Comment: Was that the whole issue, or just the issue with this?

Comment: @BenCarey No, just the reason for too-large HTML.

Comment: @BenCarey Actually it was more. Now I only have a single `div`, so apparently it's used for _all_ datepickers (or at least all popup datepickers). So it obviously can't be styled differently when it appears in different places, since it's still the same element of the tree :( So probably @Oleg's solution is the only one possible.

Comment: That sounds pretty dire! I would have thought jQuery would have accounted for issues like this! Well I hope you manage to sort it with @Olegs solution, if not, let me know and I will be glad to help. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'll have to use [beforeShow](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-beforeShow) or some other callback or event to modify the datepicker dynamically. You don't posted more details about `options1` and `options2` which you use. Probably you will have to solve more additional problems.

Comment: beforeShow can change options of datepicker, but none of them affect the CSS (or id or classes which I could use in CSS selectors).

Comment: `beforeShow` will be called at the correct moment. You can apply some modifications of the common div with id `ui-datepicker-div`. At no time It will be shown two datepicker at the same time. So I think that you can do the modifications which you need inside of `beforeShow`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Except I also need to take care to erase these modifications, and it wouldn't work if the datepicker was tied to a `div`...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Of cause you should replace or remove all previous modification from another datepicker call, but if one consider real example, then if will be possible and should be not so complex. For example you can call from `beforeShow` of both datepicker some common function which has some parameter. The function will remove some previous custom settings and apply only the settings with are needed based on the current parameters.